# Check DB size but exclude system DB

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been asked a "simple task" of pulling all used space of all our DBs  (about 50) but exclude the system DBs in each instance. My code below throws errors with my where clause. What did I forget?

```
SELECT [Database Name] = DB_NAME(database_id),
       [Size in MB] = CONCAT(CAST( ((SUM(Size)* 8) / 1024.0) AS DECIMAL(18,2) ) AS VARCHAR(20)),' MB') AS [database_size]

FROM   sys.master_files


WHERE      database_id NOT IN (‘master’, ‘tempdev’,’tempdb’……etc………)


GROUP BY      GROUPING SETS
              (
                (DB_NAME(database_id), Type_Desc),
                (DB_NAME(database_id))
              )
ORDER BY      DB_NAME(database_id), Type_Desc DESC
GO
```

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is comparing `database_id` values to the database names.

Comment: Eric,  The Where clause should only look at the instance and ignore all databases in the system databases

Comment: So let me add more details.  As our Database names are not intuitively associate-able with a given customer  my solution was a two part process.  1) get all the customer DB sizes, then order them by name and in excel add a column with the specific customer name and associate with the grouping......if this makes sense

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

try following query, you get exact output, add database name in where condition as per your requirment

```
SELECT [Database Name] = DB_NAME(database_id),
   [Size in MB] = CONCAT(CAST(((SUM(Size)* 8) / 1024.0) AS DECIMAL(18,2)),' 
MB') 

FROM   sys.master_files

WHERE  DB_NAME(database_id) NOT IN ('master', 'tempdev','tempdb')

GROUP BY      GROUPING SETS
          (
            (DB_NAME(database_id), Type_Desc),
            (DB_NAME(database_id))
          )
ORDER BY      DB_NAME(database_id), Type_Desc DESC
GO
```